# Refreshing Datagrid to the Parent page on click from the IFRAME page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, datagrid

I have a ASP.net page which has a Datagrid to display all the Records of a Table. On Click of an Add Button pops up an IFRAME with different .ASPX page to be saved as a new record. I would like to add the new record to the Datagrid on the parent page from the IFRAME.

Please suggest how can I refresh the Datagrid alone without refreshing the entire page.

Note: The Save button is in IFRAME in an another page and the Datagrid is in another Page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refresh Datagrid  only , you may consider Ajax . [Here is the link](http://fatma78.hubpages.com/hub/Automatic-Refresh-data-on-page-using-AJAX-update-panel)

Or You may also consider a java script to refresh the grid, here is the code to give you an idea

```
protected void grid_view_refesh()
{
    grid_view.Bind();
}
```

`Button:`

```
 <button id="btn_refresh" onclick="btn_refresh_click();">Refresh</button>
```

`javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function grid_view_refesh()
  {
     // you code to refresh grid
  }
```

Hope it will help

**EDITED**

You can try this code on your popup windows ( Child window)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CloseWindow() {
    window.close();
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

```
<input type="button" value="Close Window" onclick="javascript: return CloseWindow();" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the Save button is in another page. How do I invoke the grid_view_refresh() function from another C# asp.net page.

Comment: I have modified the answer, please have a look and let me know